# 'No error handlers are registered' and 'Result is not set' asyncio exceptions in Python?

Tags: ssl, python-asyncio, aiohttp, python-3.9

I'm working on a Python application that uses the telegram.ext library for handling updates from the Telegram API. However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abramov/dev/gas_tracker_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 1124, in process_update
    await coroutine
  File "/Users/abramov/dev/gas_tracker_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telegram/ext/_handler.py", line 141, in handle_update
    return await self.callback(update, context)
  File "/Users/abramov/dev/gas_tracker_bot/main.py", line 63, in get_gas_price
    eth_price = eth_price_task.result()
asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: Result is not set.
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-22' coro=<get_eth_price() done, defined at /Users/abramov/dev/gas_tracker_bot/main.py:41> exception=ClientOSError(1, '[SSL: APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2756)')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abramov/dev/gas_tracker_bot/main.py", line 43, in get_eth_price
    async with session.get(ETHER_PRICE_URL) as resp:
  File "/Users/abramov/dev/gas_tracker_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/abramov/dev/gas_tracker_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 560, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "/Users/abramov/dev/gas_tracker_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 899, in start
    message, payload = await protocol.read()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "/Users/abramov/dev/gas_tracker_bot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 616, in read
    await self._waiter
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [Errno 1] [SSL: APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2756)
```

I've tried searching for a solution and came across a similar issue (https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/6762) in which someone mentioned a possible workaround using uvloop. However, I'm not using uvloop in my project, so that solution doesn't apply to me.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error and handle these asyncio exceptions properly. Thank you in advance!

This is my code

```
async def get_eth_price(session):
    logger.info('start get_eth_price')
    async with session.get(ETHER_PRICE_URL) as resp:
        logger.info('2 get_eth_price')
        data = await resp.json()
        logger.info('3 get_eth_price')
        eth_price = data['result']['ethusd']
        logger.info('end get_eth_price')
        return eth_price


async def get_gas_price(update: telegram.Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    logger.info('start get_gas_price')
    start_time = time.time()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        eth_price_task = asyncio.create_task(get_eth_price(session))
        logger.info('1 get_gas_price')
        async with session.get(GAS_PRICE_URL) as resp:
            logger.info('2 get_gas_price')
            data = await resp.json()
            logger.info('3 get_gas_price')
            logger.info('4 get_gas_price')
            eth_price = eth_price_task.result()
            slow_gwei_price = int(data['result']['SafeGasPrice'])
            average_gwei_price = int(data['result']['ProposeGasPrice'])
            fast_gwei_price = int(data['result']['FastGasPrice'])

            slow_usd_price = await gas_price_to_usd(slow_gwei_price,
                                                    eth_price)
            logger.info('5 get_gas_price')
            average_usd_price = await gas_price_to_usd(average_gwei_price,
                                                       eth_price)

            fast_usd_price = await gas_price_to_usd(fast_gwei_price,
                                                    eth_price)
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            gas_prices_text = (
                f'Ethereum price {eth_price_task.result()}$\n\n'
                f'Slow: {slow_gwei_price} gwei {round(slow_usd_price, 2)}$\n\n'
                f'Average: {average_gwei_price} '
                f'gwei {round(average_usd_price, 2)}$\n\n'
                f'Fast: {fast_gwei_price} gwei {round(fast_usd_price, 2)}$\n\n'
                f'Elapsed time: {elapsed_time} seconds'
                )
            logger.info('end get_gas_price')
            await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                           text=gas_prices_text)
```

The error seems to be related to asyncio and an issue with SSL/TLS connections. The code in question involves making an HTTP request using aiohttp.